# MySQL: GROUP BY optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my MySQL query:

```
  SELECT [columns] FROM article a 
  LEFT JOIN category_article ca ON a.id=ca.aid
  LEFT JOIN category c1         ON c1.id=ca.cid
  LEFT JOIN navigation n        ON n.cid=c1.id
  LEFT JOIN navigation nn       ON nn.id=n.parent
  LEFT JOIN category c2         ON nn.cid=c2.id
  GROUP BY a.id
  LIMIT 10
```

and this is my execution plan:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows     Extra
1   SIMPLE  n   ref status,cid  status  1   const   13  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file...
1   SIMPLE  c1  eq_ref  PRIMARY,status_special  PRIMARY 4   tb.n.cid              1 Using where
1   SIMPLE  nn  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tb.n.parent 1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  c2  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   tb.nn.cid   1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  ca  ref cid_aid cid_aid 4   tb.n.cid    53  Using where;   Using index
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY,status_show_date    PRIMARY 4   tb.ca.aid   1   Using where
```

My guestion is I use GROUP BY for article table but MySQL change the order of joins so it using temporary and filesort and it takes quite a lot to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see tables' indexes. I suspect there is no index on "navigation.cid". Try to add an index on this column and only this one.